# Nestjs Schedule build uninterrupted cron running

Tags: nestjs

I am using nestjs schedule for my cron but I have a question.
How can I stop cron without interrupting the cron that are currently running to do a build and change the code? Or any suggestion or strategy?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem before.

- I saved all cron jobs to a dedicated table.
- I made a service to run and stop a cron job.
- Each time the server restarts, this service finds the jobs from the table and restored them.

For example:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppJobService implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  constructor(
     private schedule: SchedulerRegistry
  ) {}

  async onApplicationBootstrap() { // <- Nestjs hook invoked when the app bootstrapped
    const jobs = await Job.find(); // the jobs are all saved in `Job` table.
    jobs.forEach(job => {
        const cron = new CronJob(job.time, () => {}) // You can define the handler for each job type
        this.schedule.addCronJob(job.name, cron);
        cron.start();
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: for example I am using the decorators the cron are not lost, I just want to avoid that a running cron is interrupted when I restart with pm2 for example after I have made the build so that it takes the file changes